# sample values until getting the all the unique values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, random

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to sample the values by weights and I know there is `df.sample` function.

But the problem that I need is to get a sample that has `N` unique elements in one of the dataframe columns

Can anyone do something similar?

**edit**

example:

I have a dataframe with 1 column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,2,3,1,2,1,2,1,4,5,2,3,4,4,5,4])
```

I want to sample and in the sample I want to get 3 unique values:

possible final results:

```
[1,1,1,2,3,2,3]
```

I sample 3 different values but the sample size is larger

**edit again**

I need to sample data until I have N different values in 1 column

Answer (score 0):

You could aproach this in the different way, you can shuffle the order of the dataframe by

```
df = df.sample(len(df))
```

and then dropping duplicated from the column that you need the unique from by

```
df = df.drop_duplicated(subset = "colname")
```

which will leave you with one row for each value, you get the random sample by shuffling the df like I did before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with [`DataFrame.sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and then filter by [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) first and then apply [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503733):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,1,1,2,3,2,3,2,3,1,4,5,3,4,5,2,3,2], columns=['col'])

positions = df['col'].value_counts(normalize=True).to_dict()
print (positions)
{3: 0.2777777777777778, 
 2: 0.2777777777777778, 
 1: 0.2222222222222222, 
 5: 0.1111111111111111, 
 4: 0.1111111111111111}

def sample(obj, replace=False, total=20):
    return obj.sample(n=int(positions[obj.name] * total), replace=replace)

N = 3
v = df["col"].drop_duplicates().sample(n=N)

df1 = df[df['col'].isin(v)].groupby('col', group_keys=False).apply(sample).sort_index()
print (df1)
    col
3     2
4     3
5     2
6     3
7     2
8     3
10    4
12    3
13    4
15    2
16    3
17    2
```

Comment: in this case you not sampling from the data you are taking all the data that is in your N values
I want to sample data until i have N different values

Comment: @Dkova - Sorry, not understand. Why not expected output like `1,1,1,2,3` ? 3 different values `1,2,3`

Comment: yes but the real dataset can hold 1 10 times, and 2 4 times, and 3 5 times for example

Comment: i want a sample witht the same disrebution as the orinal dataset with all the elements inside

Comment: @Dkova - Can you check solution now?

Comment: how you calc the position table?

Comment: @Dkova - check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503733) - I add only filtring by 3 random values